# How to replace all new lines in HTML content but preserve new lines inside textarea?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have a PHP system that stores all the buffered output and before I dump it, I remove all new lines and spaces in whitespace. This works out right.

```php
$content = Buffer::getKill();
$content = preg_replace(
[
    '/[\n\r]|/',
    '# {2,}#',
    '#> <#'
],
[
    '',
    ' ',
    '><'
],
$content
);
```

the reponsavel pattern that I tried to change was the following `'/[\n\r]|/'` but I did not succeed.

The problem is that when I have a textarea within content, new textarea lines are lost as well. I've tried to do the regular expression in several ways but I can not get results, because I'm unexpected with regular expressions.

Below is an example code and its output.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <textarea>
                The
                Content
                Here 
            </textarea>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Output

```html
<html><body><div><textarea>TheContentHere</textarea></div></body></html>
```

Expected

```html
<html><body><div><textarea>
    The
    Content
    Here
</textarea></div></body></html>
```

Comment: why must you remove all of that?

Comment: I want to reduce the size of the html and make it even easier to read by browsers.

Comment: yes I thought of that, however I believe the right pattern for the regular expression would be a few thousandths faster. If you can not find the ideal solution, I'll try that way you said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex thats looks for a `>`, followed by a newline (either `\n` or `\r\n`), followed by any number of spaces and a `<`:

```
$html = preg_replace('#>[\n\r\n]?\s+<#', '><', $html);
```

Which outputs :

```
<html><body><div><textarea> 
     The 
     Content 
     Here 
     </textarea></div></body></html>
```

Which aint perfect, but closer.

Comment: `\s` already includes `\r` & `\n` so, `$html = preg_replace('#>\s+<#', '><', $html);` is enough.

Comment: Thanks Toto I didn't realise new lines were covered by the whitespace `\s`!

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!<textarea[^>]*?>)(\n)(?![^<]*?<\/textarea>)
```

this will match any newlines not between text area tags.